# problema operador ternario

Tags: javascript, angular

Se que puede sonar muy,muy basico, pero, alguien sabe porque me tira undefined la siguiente linea:

```
localStorage.getItem('id') ? true : false
```

Pero si lo hago de la siguiente, **si funciona**

```
 if (localStorage.getItem('id')){
   return true
 } else{
   return false
 }
```

Por mas que haga:

```
localStorage.getItem('id') != ''
localStorage.getItem('id') != null
localStorage.getItem('id') != undefined
Number(localStorage.getItem('id')) > 0
```

**El resultado es el mismo**

Comment: Si te lanza undefined es por qué no encontró el elemento _id_. Revisa si se está almacenando correctamente en el localStorage

Comment: Te falta `return` delante, creo

Comment: Hola, te sugiero que uses esta forma `!!localStorage.getItem('id')` no te debería traer problemas.

Comment: @PabloLozano no lleva return el ternario

Answer (score 2):

Me funciono sin problemas con:

```
!!localStorage.getItem('id')
```

Answer (score 1):

Revisa que estas haciendo, no puede darte undefined

Esta prueba sencilla lo confirma

```
localStorage.setItem('id', undefined)
localStorage.getItem('id') ? true : false // true
```

igual, como buena practica quizá te sirva

`!!localStorage.getItem('id')` que retorna true, o si quieres comparar el truthy bastaría como lo usaste en el if

Comment: Es un comentario no relacionado: ¿por qué el doble `!!` sería una buena práctica? Se produce algún tipo de cast implícito? Es que, desde acá lejos en el backend, se ve un poco _hacky_. Sería útil saber el motivo de fondo :)

Comment: @alfabravo todo depende de gustos y situaciones. 

Si el falsy basta, con `if (localStorage.getItem('foo')` funciona bien, si quiere por alguna razon un booleano, el `!!` transforma el truthy en true.

Depende de gustos imagino o necesidades especificas. He visto de todo estos años.

Lo que sí el ternario en esta situación me parece una exageración